# Huawei Push kit Change Token expiración Time

Tags: push-notification, push, huawei-mobile-services, pushkit

It's possible to change the expiration time response variable huawei  (expires_in) when we obtain a new token for send push kit notification?, or what would be the best way to renew this token on my server

by default the variable (expires_in) is set in 3600 seconds i like to change this number to more time.

the documentation don't show nothing for change this variable, its only show:

Send a POST request. Example:

1. POST /oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1
2. Host: oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com
3. Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
4. grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=**<Client ID>**&client_secret=**<Client secret>**

**Response message:**

1. HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2. Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
3. Cache-Control: no-store
4. {
5. "access_token": "<**Returned access token**>",
6. "expires_in": 3600,
7. "token_type": "Bearer"
8. }

[response vars descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VEra.png)

change the expiration time response variable (expires_in)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?:

4. grant_type=client_credentials&t**ime_out=4500**&client_id=&client_secret=